# NameError: name 'fetch' is not defined in Selenium Console

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, fetch

Hi I am trying to open Selenium, visit a URL then use driver.execute_script to send a fetch request via Console in Chrome Developer Tools within the Selenium window.

However when I run it, the Selenium window opens up, visits the page, but when it gets to the execute_script section, it comes up with:

'NameError: name 'fetch' is not defined'. How do I fix this? Thanks

```
driver.get(URL1)
driver.get('URL')

payload = fetch("URL", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "sec-ch-device-memory": "8",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"107\", \"Chromium\";v=\"107\", \"Not=A?Brand\";v=\"24\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-arch": "\"x86\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-full-version-list": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"107.0.5304.88\", \"Chromium\";v=\"107.0.5304.88\", \"Not=A?Brand\";v=\"24.0.0.0\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-model": "",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "x-esro-af": "s9TeAPYWl4s=",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
  },
  "referrer": "URL",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": URL CONTENT",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});

driver.execute_script(f'{payload}')
```

I have tried putting "" to wrap the whole payload but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is `fetch` supposed to be?  A local function, or part of some module?

Comment: On a POST request I've 'Copy as fetch'. My intention is for the Selenium Window to paste it into the console in Chrome Web Developer Tools and have it post the request. 

I am able to do this manually by doing:

Copy as Fetch -> Paste into Console -> Hit Enter, and it POSTS the request for me that I copied the request from. So I'm just trying to do it on Selenium, not me doing it manually on a real browser. @JohnGordon

Comment: If you want to send arbitrary web requests, use `requests.post()`.  (requests is a third-party module so you will have to install it)

Comment: @JohnGordon Unfortunately due to the nature of what this project involves I need to do it this way, hopefully there's a solution

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "do it this way".  There is no function named `fetch()`, so you obviously _can't_ do that...

Comment: Where did you get the function name `fetch`?  Is that copied from some javascript code?

Comment: Yes, so, on a normal browser, I open Inspect -> Network -> Find the POST request I want -> Right click and Copy as Fetch.

On the same browser I can paste it into the console and hit ENTER and it POSTs the form data.

UPDATE: I've fixed it, I had to just put '' around fetch, as it is not a function as you said, but part of the string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @John fetch is a window method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how fetch works. first of all it runs in the browser, and second it's async so use execute_async_script.

It should look something like this:

```
response = driver.execute_async_script("""
  let [resolve] = arguments
  fetch(url, options).then(r => r.text()).then(resolve)
""")
```